# How prove this $2^{a_{1}}\cdot~3^{a_{2}}\cdot 4^{a_{3}}\cdots 10^{a_{9}}\le n+1$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Assmue that give the postive integers $n$,and the decimal the digits of the postive integer $n$(in base 10),there are $a_{1}$ number 1,$a_{2}$ number 2,$a_{3}$ number $3$,$\cdots\cdots$,$a_{9}$ number $9$.
show that
$$2^{a_{1}}\cdot~3^{a_{2}}\cdot 4^{a_{3}}\cdots 10^{a_{9}}\le n+1$$

if $n$ only have one digits,then $a_{n }=1,1\le n<1$,and $a_{i}=0,i\neq n$,it is clear 
$$2^{a_{1}}3^{a_{2}}\cdots 10^{a_{9}}\le n+1$$

but How to prove other case

Comment: Can you be more clear? There aren't too many numbers that are equal to how many decimal digits they have.

Comment: @DavidP The OP means $a_i$ is the number of $i$ appearing when writing $n$ is base $10$. So $i\in \{0,\ldots,9\}$. For example, $11132$ and $31211$ both have $a_0=,a_1=3,a_2=1,a_3=1,a_4=0,\ldots$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff,Thank you that's your mean

Answer (score 6):

How many non-negative numbers are less than or equal to $n$ ? Clearly $n+1$.

How many non-negative numbers $x$ satisfy that when written in decimal every digit of $n$ is larger or equal to the digit of $x$ in the same position? Clearly $1^{a_0}2^{a_1}\dots 10^{a_9}$, and every number of this form is clearly smaller than or equal to $n$.

We conclude $n+1\geq 1^{a_0}2^{a_2}\dots 10^{a_9}$

Comment: The equality holds if and only if $n$ is of the form $\overline{t99\ldots9}_{10}$ where $t\in\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$.  Very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use induction to show this (not as slick though).
Induct on the number of digits. Suppose the last digit of $n$ is $k\in \{0, \cdots, 9\}$. By induction hypothesis, $2^a_1 \cdots (k+1)^{a_k-1}\cdots 10^{a_9}\leq (\frac{n-k}{10}+1)$. Multiply both side by $k+1$, we are left to show that $(\frac{n-k}{10}+1)(k+1)\leq n+1$ for any such $k$. For $k=9$ this is always true. If $k<9$, by rearranging above equation (solving for n) we get $n\geq \frac{9k-k^2}{9-k}=k$ which is obviously true.